# Eclipse RCP export product custom plugins not exported

Tags: eclipse, export, wizard, rcp, product

I use Eclipse Product export wizard to create my application distributable image. The export want without errors, but the result contains only the eclipse.org.* plugins, none of my application plugins.

Comment: Hi, did you finally solve your problem (I know it was a long time ago...) ? We have been suddenly hit by exactly the same issue and I dont find any solution anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

To add your own Plug-In's to the product configuration, you can do the following:

1. Open the **.product* file and switch to the **Dependencies** tab
2. Use the **Add** button to add your Plug-In's

And you're done.

*Optional:* Hit the **Add Required Plug-ins** to add the Plug-ins required by your own Plug-in.